ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : use queryString on complex json can not bind successfully
When I use the GET API to send a complex JSON format, the backend cannot obtain the data correctly.
This my query string data:
{
    "page": 1,
    "page_size": 10,
    "sortBy": 
    [
        {"key": "reservation_no", "order": "desc"},
        {"key": "pr_no", "order": "desc"},
        {"key": "pr_item", "order": "asc"}
    ]
}

Then it will be converted to this format
?page=1&page_size=11&sortBy[0][key]=reservation_no&sortBy[0][order]=desc&sortBy[1][key]=pr_no&sortBy[1][order]=desc&sortBy[2][key]=pr_item&sortBy[2][order]=asc

My backend can get page and page_size, but sortBy is null.

CustomQueryParametersBinder:
using complex_json_can_not_bind_successful.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace complex_json_can_not_bind_successful
{
    public class CustomQueryParametersBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var query = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;

            var pageValue = query["page"].FirstOrDefault();
            var pageSizeValue = query["page_size"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortByValues = query.Where(q => q.Key.StartsWith("sortBy")).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.ToString());

            var result = new QueryParameters
            {
                Page = int.TryParse(pageValue, out var page) ? page : 1,
                PageSize = int.TryParse(pageSizeValue, out var pageSize) ? pageSize : 10,
                SortBy = sortByValues
                    .GroupBy(kv => int.Parse(kv.Key.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0]))
                    .Select(g => new SortOption
                    {
                        Key = g.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key.Contains("key")).Value,
                        Order = g.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key.Contains("order")).Value
                    })
                    .ToList()
            };

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}

How to use it:
[HttpGet("method2")]
public IActionResult Get2([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomQueryParametersBinder))] QueryParameters queryParameters)
{
    return Ok(queryParameters);
}

You can use sample code like this:

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] int page, [FromQuery(Name = "page_size")] int pageSize)
    {
        var sortBy = Request.Query
            .Where(q => q.Key.StartsWith("sortBy"))
            .GroupBy(kv => int.Parse(kv.Key.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0]))
            .Select(g => new SortOption
            {
                Key = g.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key.Contains("key")).Value.ToString(),
                Order = g.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key.Contains("order")).Value.ToString()
            })
            .ToList();

        var queryParameters = new QueryParameters
        {
            Page = page,
            PageSize = pageSize,
            SortBy = sortBy
        };

        // Your logic here
        return Ok(queryParameters);
    }
}

Models:
public class SortOption
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
}

public class QueryParameters
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public List<SortOption> SortBy { get; set; }
}


Can I customize IModelBinder to handle this?

@LanLin Updated. Please let me know if it helps.

This method works, thank you!!
